# File transfer to Raspberry with Python language

Tags: python, file, raspberry-pi

I am doing a project where I need to make a communication channel between a PC and Raspberry Pi, this channel should be able to transfer text files from pc to a folder in Raspberry.

The PC and RBPi are conected throught network.

The security is not really relevant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Set up a shared directory that both the Raspberry Pi and the PC can share - it could be physically hosted on either machine https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/samba-file-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is by sending a file over SSH using SFTP. This doesn't require any additional setup on the Pi, except assuming you have SSH open on your Pi (there are plenty of tutorials online on this).

A pure python solution to this could use the Paramiko library to connect to the Pi and copy the file. Here is a quick example:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.connect('192.168.1.30', username='pi', password='raspberry') # Default IP/login, this may be different for you
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
# Localpath is a string containing the path of the local file, remotepath is where the file should be copied on the raspberry pi
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

There are many solutions to this problem (eg. setting up a fileserver), but I think this is the simplest. If using python is not vital then I just recommend using the linux `scp`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, something simple yet powerful. Thank you!